# JavaScript + Discord.js: Object inside another object returns TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror, discord.js

So I'm building a RPG bot for Discord, and I'm making the equipment system (you know, swords, armor). I ran into an error where all other `userData` objects worked, but only the equipment object returns `undefined` when I logged it to the console. I tried `Object.assign(userData[message.author.id].equipment, {equipmentData})` when the user ran `!setup`, but that returned `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. Here is my code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!userData[message.author.id]) {
        userData[message.author.id] = {
            equipment: {
                example_weapon: {
                    ID: 0,
                    Attack: 0,
                    Rarity: "somerarity",
                    Owned: 0
                },
                example_armor: {
                    ID: 0,
                    Defense: 0,
                    Rarity: "",
                    Owned: 0
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Note: I left out the code that's not important, for example, the other objects stored in userData.

Comment: Seems like equipmentData is not defined, are you sure you defined/imported it before assigning?

Comment: equipmentData was an example, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Well another thing I just noticed: If you put `{ }` around the object you are trying to assign, it creates a new object, so it should be `Object.assign(userData[message.author.id].equipment, equipmentData)`, however this also depends on how your code is structured. It may also work like that, it may be nice if you could provide a bit more code

Comment: The object and all of it's properties return undefined. So I tried to leave the object itself empty when its first called, and afterwards apply the value to it with `Object.assign();`. Problem is, the object itself seems to never have been defined in the first place, as the empty object still returns undefined.

Comment: Could you share some more code? Where you create the object etc, basically everything that is only remotely related to this. This sounds like a little typo here or there but I can't say it with only this small amount of code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/St3bzphz
I think this will be all you need. It contains all places with code surrounding equipment.